# java run compiled class file from another program issue

Tags: java, class, javac

In my program I'm trying to compile and run some java code, that I get from a TextField, when I click a button. To compile the code, i use:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector();

StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("Code.java"));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
boolean succ = task.call();
```

Then I'm calling the main method of my code.class class

`Code.main(new String[0]);`

The first time i compile and run the code via a button click, it works fine, but when I change the code in the TextField and compile and run it again, it doesn't update, but the old code runs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you run the compiled program (`code`) in the same JVM as the calling program? If so, keep in mind that as soon as the JVM has loaded a class that class is meant to stay. You'd need to apply some class loader magic in order to be able to "forget" the previous version, and load a new version after recompile.

Here "magic" could be as simple as:

- Explicitly create your own class loader
- Load the freshly compiled class into that class loader
- When re-compiling, discard the previous class loader, and start over.

Note 1: you didn't show the exact sequence of invoking `main`, but apparently you'd need to use reflection to call code that was not present when compiling your application.

Note 2: according to convention, `code` would be the name of a variable. If that is supposed to be the name of a class, it would be clearer if you use class spelling / capitalization: `Code`.

Comment: I used an example from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0125__Reflection/DynamicallyReloadingaModifiedClass.htm) to reload my class:

`URL[] urls = null;


 File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "dir" + File.separator);

 URL url = dir.toURI().toURL();

 urls = new URL[] { url };

 ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

 Class cls = cl.loadClass("Code");

 Code myObj = (Code) cls.newInstance();

 myObj.main(new String[0]);`
But it still doesn't work,